# How to delete a pushed git merge commit

Tags: git, git-commit, git-revert

I merged a couple of devel commits into the master branch of my repo just to find out that GitAhead screwed up the master at some point.

Now I tried various methods described on SO in order to undo these commits (there is no other commit than merges on master). This way master was indeed reset to an earlier version.

However, I still have the full merge history in headless branches (the grey path on the image):

[image]

I tried to revert, reset, etc the branch without success alas!

How can I fully delete the commits (c518859ce4, 7574f10f68)?

Comment: The problem is the tag on the first commit. It is keeping the ghost commits alive. Get rid of it and checkout your reset master.

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks so much!

Comment: Yay! I like when that happens. I’ll give that as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the tag on the first commit. It is keeping the ghost commits alive.

Get rid of the tag and checkout your reset master (which I presume is somewhere further down the chart). Your history will then look correct.

Answer (score 1):

**1) option revert:**

```
   git revert c518859ce4
    git revert 7574f10f68
```

**Then you can push:**

```
git push
```

Comment: This does not seem to solve the issue unless I do something wrong: this will create a merge commit and not delete the wrong/unnecessary commit! Is there NO way to delete a branch or headless branch starting at a certain position completely?! No merge, no backup, just undo the wrong commit(s)?!

Comment: OK just a note for readers: it does work, as long as there is no Tag preventing the commits to be garbage collected (see answer)!